# Windows shared memory access time slow

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, shared-memory

I am currently using shared memory with two mapped files (1.9 GBytes for the first one and 600 MBytes for the second) in a software.
I am using a process that read data from the first file, process the data and write the results to the second file.
I have noticed a strong delay sometimes (the reason is out of my knowledge) when reading or writing to the mapping view with memcpy function.

Mapped files are created this way :

```
m_hFile = ::CreateFileW(SensorFileName, 
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                        0,
                        NULL,
                        CREATE_ALWAYS,
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL);

m_hMappedFile = CreateFileMapping(m_hFile,
                                  NULL,
                                  PAGE_READWRITE,
                                  dwFileMapSizeHigh,
                                  dwFileMapSizeLow,
                                  NULL);
```

And memory mapping is done this way :

```
m_lpMapView = MapViewOfFile(m_hMappedFile, 
                            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                            dwOffsetHigh,
                            dwOffsetLow,
                            m_i64ViewSize);
```

The dwOffsetHigh/dwOffsetLow are "matching" granularity from the system info.

The process is reading about 300KB * N times, storing that in a buffer, processing and then writing 300KB * N times the processed contents of the previous buffer to the second file.
I have two different memory views (created/moved with MapViewOfFile function) with a size of 10 MBytes as default size.
For memory view size, I tested 10kBytes, 100kB, 1MB, 10MB and 100MB. 
Statistically no difference, 80% of the time reading process is as described below (~200ms) but writing process is really slow.

Normally :
 1/ Reading is done in ~200ms.
 2/ Process done in 2.9 seconds.
 3/ Writing is done in ~200ms.

I can see that 80% of the time, either reading or writing (in the worst case both are slow) will take between 2 and 10 seconds.

Example : For writing, I am using the below code

```
for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)  // N = 500~3k
{
    // Check the position of the memory view for ponderation
    if (###)
        MoveView(iOffset);

    if (m_lpMapView)
    {
        memcpy((BYTE*)m_lpMapView + iOffset, pANNHeader, uiANNStatus);
        // uiSize = ~300 kBytes
        memcpy((BYTE*)m_lpMapView + iTemp, pLine[i], uiSize);
    }
    else
        return uiANNStatus;
}
```

After using GetTickCount function to pinpoint where is the delay, I am seeing that the second memcpy call is always the one taking most of the time.
So, so far I am seeing N (for test, I used N = 500) calls to memcpy taking **10 seconds** at the worst time when using those shared memories.
I made a temporary software that was doing the same quantity of memcpy calls, same amount of data and couldn't see the problem.

For tests, I used the following conditions, they all show the same delay :
1/ I can see this on various computers, 32 or 64 bits from windows 7 to windows 10.
2/ Using the main thread or multi-threads (up to 8 with critical sections for synchronization purpose) for reading/writing.
3/ OS on SATA or SSD, memory mapped files of the software physically on a SATA or SSD hard-disk, and if on external hard-disk, tests were done through USB1, USB2 or USB3.

I am kindly asking you what you would think my mistake is for memcpy to go slow.

Best regards.

Comment: That's normal with memory mapped files. At some point, it needs to physically commit data to disks - and your are disk IO bound.

Comment: You may want to profile against a code change where you are buffering the data and not using memory mapped files.  Alter the size of the buffer than the input block size to gain performance.

Comment: Search the MSDN site for an API which can lock your memory to prevent the OS from swapping it with hard disk.

Comment: @Sergey, the user's thread should not be waiting for these io completions. At least in Linux.

Comment: I believe the moveview is making too many memcpy calls to cause page misses. Can you try one big view instead of many small ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me but not might be the case for others.
Following Thomas Matthews comments, I checked the MSDN and found two interesting functions FlushViewOfFile and FlushFileBuffers (but couldn't find anything interesting about locking memory).
Calling both after the for loop force update of the mapped file.
I am having no more "random" delay, but instead of the expected 200ms, I have an average of 400ms which is enough for my application.

After doing some tests I saw that calling those too often will cause heavy hard-disk access and will make the delay worse (10 seconds for every for loop) so the flush should be use carefully.

Thanks.